# Entity\EntityStorageInterface::loadMultiple() expects array|null, array|int given

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

Does anyone know why I get this error? The code does what is supposed to, but when I check with Phing I get:

> Parameter #1 $ids of method "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface::load multiple()" expects array|null, array|int given.

```
$comment_ids = $this->entityTypeManager
    ->getStorage('comment')
    ->getQuery('AND')
    ->condition('entity_id', $entity->id())
    ->condition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->sort('cid', 'DESC')
    ->execute();
  
  $comments = $this->entityTypeManager
    ->getStorage('comment')
    ->loadMultiple($comment_ids);
```

Comment: Have you tried to fetch the results on the query you have executed? :)

Comment: Hi can you elaborate , what do you mean by that?

Comment: When you are calling the `execute()` method at the end of your query, you get a boolean value if the execution was successful or not. In order to populate your variable with results, you'll need to fetch the data on that query, meaning you need to call one of the fetch methods available like `fetch()`, `fetchAll()`, `fetchAllAssoc()` .. so on. Either one works, but keep in mind one of them gives you back an stdClass, the other an associated array, so always check the data before you work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Because method `Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryInterface::execute()` can return an `integer` or an `array` while `Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface::loadMultiple()` accepts only `array` or `null` as parameter, so **Phing** warned you as above.

But you don't need to worry about that, because method `execute()` only returns `int` when you call `count()` before. In the case of your code, it always returns an `array`.